# c - find all possible combinations of a string in another string

Tags: c

Suppose I have a string "ron". I need to find all combinations of "ron" in a string, suppose "**xxxxxxronxxxxnorxxxxxrno**". The output should be ron, nor, rno were found in the string.

One way to do that would be to first generate all combinations of "ron" and then check for these substrings in the original string, using something like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int count, occur; 
char *str[100];

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/* Function to print permutations of string
   This function takes three parameters:
   1. String
   2. Starting index of the string
   3. Ending index of the string. */
void permute(char *a, int i, int n) 
{
   int j; 
   if (i == n)
     //printf("%s\t", a);
     {
        str[count++]=a;
        printf("%s\t", str[count-1]);
     }    

   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
} 

void substring(char *b, int i)
{
    char *tmp = b;
    while(tmp = strstr(tmp, str[i]))
    {
       occur++;
       tmp++;
    }
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
   char a[] = "ABC";
   char b[] = "ABCRTYBACXCAB";    
   int i;

   count=0;
   occur=0;

   permute(a, 0, 2);

   for(i=0;i<count;i++)
      printf("%s\t", str[i]);

   for(i=0;i<count;i++)
      substring(b,i);

   printf("\nOccurences: %d", occur);

   return 0;
}
```

When I execute this, I get output as:

ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB

ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC

Occurences: 6

The values of str in permute are showing correctly, but why are they different in main?
What's going wrong?

**Solved:**

str[count++]=strdup(a);

or

converted *str[] to str[][] and then did strcpy(str[],a)

Comment: At least the string is not "enron"!!!

Comment: I like your solution better than PandaConda's below.  It's much easier to follow what is going on, which is #1 when writing maintainable code.  Just put the code you put up there in another loop that iterates through all possible combinations of "ron" and you're golden.

Comment: Given `"ronronron"`, what should the answer be ? 3 or 7 ?

Comment: @c.fogelklou: Did you realize that there is up to `n!` permutations of string of length `n`? Sometimes the easy way is not so easy. Are you sure you want to apply your approach to string of length 10?

Comment: More importantly, are you asking for permutations or combinations of the string? *Permutations* of `ron` will be `ron, rno, ...`, while its *combinations* will be `r, o, n, on, no, ...`. I hope you see the difference. Now in your original problem, you just matched `ron, nor, rno`, which are permutations. `ronronron` *does not* have a permutation in your original string. It does have several combinations (but many more than 7). So your question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: @ssm i'm sorry, the answer should be 7

Comment: @gmch I'm sorry, the answer should be 7

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil I'm only applying this to strings of length 3-4 characters

Comment: @Engineer: Can you enumerate the permutations please? Permutations for `ronronron` are `rrrooonnn, rrroonnno, ...`. I don't see any of these strings within `xxxxxxronxxxxnorxxxxxrno`. On the other hand, If you consider `ron` as a valid string, then you will need to consider `r, r, r, o, o, o, n, n, n, ro, ro, ro, ro, ro, ro, ro, ro, ro, ...` as valid solutions. As you see, you have already exceeded 7.

Comment: @ssm permutations for ron are ron, rno, onr, orn, nor, nro. We're not considering permutations for ronronron, we're considering permutations for only ron

Comment: @Engineer: Can same letters repeat in first string?

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil no

Comment: @Engineer Nice, so I think I have pretty simple solution with O(N+M) time complexity where `N` and `M` are sizes of both strings. I will try describe when I will be less busy.

Answer (score 1):

First make [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) state machine for all `"ron"` permutations (which is nice exercise alone) and then apply this machine to your second string. It is pretty efficient solution short first string.

**Edit**: I have realized that Aho-Corasick state machines would require `N!` internal states which blows it up anyway. There have to be constructed some other sort of state machine with *condensed* state. I'm thinking about linked list of found substring so far with hash or linear table pointing to each part.

**Edit2**: There is solution with `O(N+M)` time and `O(A)` space complexity where `N` and `M` are sizes of input string and `A` is size of alphabet on [GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/pichi/f14cbae6387220daa812). It uses bitmap to track characters which belongs to sublist and which found in string and back reference pointers where each character found so far. All state size for ASCII is 2128 at 64bit platform which nicely fits in L1 CPU cache of modern HW.

Answer (score 1):

The following is pretty general...

```
  char test[] = "xxxronronronxxx" ;
  const char* s ;

  s = test ;

  const char* seek = "ron" ;
  int count = 0 ;
  while (1)
    {
      char find[strlen(seek) + 1] ;
      const char* t ;
      int n ;

      s = strpbrk(s, seek) ;
      if ((s == NULL) || (strlen(s) < strlen(seek)))
        break ;

      strcpy(find, seek) ;
      t = s ;
      n = strlen(find) ;
      while (1)
        {
          char* f ;

          f = strchr(find, *t) ;
          if (f == NULL)
            break ;

          n -= 1 ;
          if (n == 0)
            {
              count += 1 ;
              break ;
            } ;

          *f = find[n] ;
          find[n] = '\0' ;

          t += 1 ;
        } ;

      s += 1 ;
    } ;

  printf("'%s' in '%s' %d times\n", seek, test, count) ;
```

... the `s += 1` at the end could be `s += strlen(seek)` to step past the match, if that's what's required.

Comment: This code is working correctly, but what is the error in my code?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your `permute()` function with a debugger ?  When you store a pointer to one of your permutations, what is it pointing at ?

Comment: Indeed.  What you didn't say is whether you are worried about how well this performs, how flexible you need it to be (different strings to search for, string lengths, etc.)  As noted elsewhere, as your string to search for increases in size, so constructing the table of permutations gets to be more work !  If the string you are searching through is short, then the overhead of constructing the permutations could look silly.  If the string you are searching through is very long, then you are doing a separate seach for every permutation !

Comment: `strlen` function is searching for end of string which makes it `N^2` behavior just in this one (strlen(s) < strlen(seek)) condition for each position. Try the code for few hundreds of MB and see what happen.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Sure... that can be improved... thinking about it, it's just as easy to look for `*t == '\0'`.  The `char find[]` creation can be moved out of the loop.  The various `strlen(seek/find)` ditto.  Filling the `find[]` could be changed to a `memcpy()`, since the length is fixed and well known.  But I'm not trying to do *all* the work :-)  If performance is really critical, and very large strings are being searched, then having a separate `find` string for each possible first letter, would mean that the set up and the inner loop would happen after the 2nd good char.